# accessiablity of global variables in class and function

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I am confused about the global variables which start with `__` in `Python`. And I wonder why variables like `__XXX` cannot be accessed in `class function`

Here is my code:

```
__global_var = 'first'
global_var = 'second'

class TestClass(object):
    """docstring for Test"""
    def __init__(self):
        global __global_var
        global global_var
        print global_var, __global_var


def test_func():
    global __global_var
    global global_var
    print global_var, __global_var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_func()
    test_class = TestClass()
```

And the output is:

```
second first
second
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_global.py", line 19, in <module>
    test_class = TestClass()
  File "test_global.py", line 9, in __init__
    print global_var, __global_var
NameError: global name '_TestClass__global_var' is not defined
```

Could anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: That's not a duplicate of the linked question although it accounts for half of the issue you have here. Name mangling inserts `_classname` as prefix to your variable, but such a global name doesn't exist, hence the NameError you get. Don't use double-underscore prefixes for globals.

Comment: @Darkonaut Thanks for your answer. I read it and the linked question carefully, i think, i can clear my confusion now.